# How to ignore the property of the base class in the derived class while using the XmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, xmlserializer, messagecontract

I have a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Structure
    {
        #region Constants and Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The description.
        /// </summary>
        private string description;


        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        ///   Gets or sets the Description of the subclass i.e subtype of structure
        /// </summary>
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return this.description;
            }

            set
            {
                this.description = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Another class like below inherits above one:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "TestNamespace", ElementName = "OrgStructure")]
    public class OrgStructure : Structure
    {


        private long orgDeptID;

        /// <summary>
        ///   The description
        /// </summary>
        private string description;

  public long OrgDeptID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.orgDeptID;
            }

            set
            {
                this.orgDeptID= value;

            }
        }
}
```

I am migrating ASMX service to WCF keeping them compatible with existing ASMX clients. So I have to use the `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer`.

The `OrgStructure` is declared as `MessageBodyMember` in the response type of an  `OperationContract`.

The ASMX client **does NOT** expect the `Description` in the XML message. So I tried to hide (using `new` operator) the `Description` property in the derived class and applied `XmlIgnoreAttribute` to it. But still it serializes this property.

(Please note that the declaration of the `description` variable. I do not know why developer declared again the derived class instead keeping it `protected` in the base class itself.)

How can I ignore the property of the base class in the derived class while using the XmlSerializer? I cannot ignore it in the base class since other subtypes of `Structure` need it.

Comment: OrgDeptID is a stackoverflow, BTW - typo?

Comment: @Marc : I did not get (`OrgDeptID is a stackoverflow`) your question. I have not copied entire code here. I just wrote couple of properties here to simulate scenario.

Comment: And OrgStructure.description (field) is never used; throw it away.

Comment: look carefully; `OrgDeptID` calls `OrgDeptID`, which calls `OrgDeptID`, which calls `OrgDeptID` - it should be `return orgDeptID` (note the lower case `o`). Not major, but it tripped me for a half-second.

Comment: @Marc: I appreciate your observation (+1). I am at fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the base class, add:

```
public virtual bool ShouldSerializeDescription() { return true; }
```

and to the derived class, add:

```
public override bool ShouldSerializeDescription() { return false; }
```

This is a pattern that `XmlSerializer` recognises, but must be declared at the same level as the member (`Description`), hence the need to make it `virtual`.

If it offends the eye, add some:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

to it - but it *must* be `public` to work.

Comment: What an awesome answer!!! Thanks a lot. From where did you learn this ? Could you please point readers to some MS documentation where this or relevant thing is discussed?

Comment: @CSharpLearner if I ever find it, I'll let you know ;p IIRC it is discussed in the `[DefaultValue]` discussion, and in `PropertyDescriptor`, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.canresetvalue.aspx

Comment: I have found two useful links related to it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=VS.100).aspx and http://funcakes.posterous.com/using-shouldserialize-for-conditional-omissio